# Issue opening new window in python with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to know how I can connect my function to a window I created using tkinter. I have tried numerous ways of connecting them but it wont work. I'm trying to display my database in a new window.

```
import sys  # Import the sys 
from Tkinter import * # Makign a Window from the library
import Tkinter as tk
import sqlite3 as sql # Connection 
con = sql.connect('ALL') # Connection to database and name 
cur = con.cursor() # Connection to database

def onclick(obj):

  data = obj.data_customer()
  for row in data:
    print(row)

  root = tk.Tk()
  root.title("Customer Data")
  root.geometry("200x100+30+30")
  root.configure(bg="white")
  button = tk.Button(onclick, text="Lift", command=onclick(obj))
  button.pack

  #root = Tk()   #create the root window
  #root.data
  #root.title("Data") #modify the window
  #root.geometry("800x800")
  #root.mainloop()  #Start the window's event-loop

  #root = Tk()
  #text.insert(INSERT, "")
  #text.insert(END, self.data_customer)
  #text.pack()
  #root.title("CustomerData") #changes title name
  #onclick(data)
  #root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly you already have a window and you want to display your data in a new one.

In that case you should try [Tkinter's toplevel widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm). Simply add your data on the toplevel and it will be displayed in a new window

Comment: What does that mean? Is that using top = Toplevel() and passing my function as the argument?

Comment: You can add widgets to a toplevel just like how you would add them to any other widget. If for example you have a label you want to add to the toplevel you would do `mylabel = Label(top, text="my text")` . Of course you'll also have to use a geometry manager to properly place them inside the window. Hope that helps.